Flask api route doesn't work when splitting into multiple files
I'm having trouble running flask rest api when splitting a flask app into multiple files.
When running this on Postman : http://127.0.0.1:5000/domains, I have a 404 not Found error. But when I put everything within app.py, it works great.
Here is the skeleleton of my project :
test-app/
 .venv/
 common/
  models/
   __init__.py
   domain.py
   subdomain.py
  routes/
   __init__.py
   domain_route.py
   subdomain_route.py
  daos/
   domain_dao.py
   subdomain_dao.py
 app.py

models/domain.py (very similar to subdomain.py)
from dataclasses import dataclass
from . import db

@dataclass
class Domain(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'domain'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True} 

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)

app.py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, json
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.event import listens_for
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
from flask_cors import CORS
from dataclasses import dataclass
from sqlalchemy import text
from urllib.parse import quote
from flask_migrate import Migrate    

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, origins=["http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:3000"])


from app.models import db
from common.routes import *
app.register_blueprint(domain_route)  

mysql =MySQL()

@dataclass
class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(46), nullable=False)
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(46), nullable=False)
    

    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname

    def as_dict(self):
        excluded_fields = ['id']
        return {field.name:getattr(self, field.name) for field in self.__table__.c if field.name not in excluded_fields}

@dataclass
class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'user'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True} 

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(46), nullable=False)#1
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(46), nullable=False)#1

    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname

    def as_dict(self):
        excluded_fields = ['id']
        return {field.name:getattr(self, field.name) for field in self.__table__.c if field.name not in excluded_fields}



app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://username:pwd@127.0.0.1/test'

db.init_app(app)
with app.app_context():
    from app.models import *
    migrate = Migrate(app, db)
    db.create_all()


@app.route('/users', methods=['GET'])
def get_user():
    users = User.query.all()
    return jsonify(users)

@app.route('/user/<firstname>', methods=['GET'])
def user_byfirstname(firstname):
    user = User.query.filter_by(firstname = firstname).first()
    return jsonify(user.as_dict())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)

routes/__init__.py
from flask import Blueprint
routes = Blueprint('routes', __name__)

from .domain_route import *

routes/domain_route.py
from flask import request, jsonify
from common.daos.domain_dao import domain_dao
from common.models.domain import Domain
from . import routes


@routes.route('/domains', methods=['GET'])
def get_domains():
    print('##### get_domains')
    domain = domain_dao.get_all()
    return jsonify(domain)

daos/domain_dao.py
from common.models.domain import Domain


class DomainDAO:
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model    
    
    def get_all(self):
        return Domain.query.all()
  
domain_dao = DomainDAO(Domain)

http://127.0.0.1:5000/domains triggers an error but if I do everything within app.py, it will work. What's wrong please ?
